# Plugin link does not appear in my toolbar

Tags: plugins, admin-menu, admin-bar, user-interface

I haven't installed anything that would break the link, as far as I can tell it's just never been there. I have no idea what to do, please help.

Comment: Provide detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

Is the issue that you have no way to get to your plugins from the wordpress admin/dashboard  screen?

If this is the case, you may have set your user as something other than an administrator. Although, if your wordpress installation only has one account, then this likely is not the case.

In the admin area (yoursite.com/wp-admin or yoursite.com/[yourwordpressroot]/wp-admin) go to users > all users  and look at what role is next to your username. If you can't access "all users" and can only access "Your Profile" under "Users", then you definitely do not have your account set as an administrator.